# git clone over https empty clone

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone from my solaris machine using this command.,but it doesn't create a clone , its just exit during clone command run, and if I check the clone directory, its not created.

Please share your thoughts. Thanks

```
/usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.6

GIT_TRACE=1 /usr/local/bin/git clone -v https://github.domain.com/Repo/myrepo.git --progress
trace: built-in: git 'clone' '-v' 'https://github.domain.com/Repo/myrepo.git' '--progress'
Cloning into myrepo...
```

nothing created

Comment: You can try adding `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1` and `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to the command line to get more information.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I am getting this error if I add those trace commands   * Couldn't find host github.domain.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to github.domain.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.1681.1.... * Connected to github.domain.com (192.1681.1.) port 443 (#0)

Comment: @scm please add any additional information to your question (rather than hiding it in comments)

Comment: hi, I just used clone command with trace options GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 and GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1,  I am trying to clone it in my solaris box, its just exit with this error  * Couldn't find host github.domain.com in the .netrc file; using defaults * About to   GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 /usr/local/bin/git clone -v https://github.domain.com/Repo/myrepo.git connect() to github.domain.com port 443,  there is no clone directory created

Comment: hi, sorry, this issue is due to Git version installed. earlier I tried Git version at  1.7.6 , it's not cloned. Now, I tried at version git version 1.8.5.2 , I can able to clone from Solaris machine, thanks